# When is $sec^2\theta$=$\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}$ true?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is-

$sec^2\theta$=$\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}$ is true if and only if:

So, I was thinking to add $(x-y)^2$ and $(x+y)^2$, but, I am not able to get anywhere. Kindly help with any hint or clue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't really understand you question

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you tell the part where you would like me to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\tan^2\theta=\dfrac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}-1=-\left(\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2$$

$$\implies\tan^2\theta+\left(\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2=0$$

Now for real $a, a^2\ge0$